# How to Declare Canvas2Image Plugin in config.xml using Phonegap 2.4

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, cordova-3

I want to use Canvas2Image  plugin for my iOS application to save the image. And i'm using PhoneGap 2.9 which is compatible with Xcode 5. I don't know how to declare plugin in PhoneGap 2.9 . Could anybody tell me how the bindings of Plugin take place in PhoneGap 2.9.

Link for the plugin 
https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Though i added both .h & .m to to project I copied the Canvas2ImagePlugin.js to my directory. Plugin is not getting called .

Any help will be really appreciable.

And my Config.xml has the following format

```
    <plugins></plugins>

    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture"/>
    <plugin name="ChildBrowserCommand" value="ChildBrowserCommand"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />

    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts"/>
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation"/>
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification"/>
    <plugin name="PushNotification" value="PushNotification"/>
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner"/>
    <plugin name="com.tesitng.Canvas2ImagePlugin" value="Canvas2ImagePlugin"/>

</plugins>
<access origin="*"/>
```

And i added Canvas2ImagePlugin.h  & Canvas2ImagePlugin.m to plugins folder of cordova project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I see you're using the old plugins format, I edited my answer based on your edited question :-) Try this:

```
<plugins>   
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture"/>
    <plugin name="ChildBrowserCommand" value="ChildBrowserCommand"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts"/>
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation"/>
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification"/>
    <plugin name="PushNotification" value="PushNotification"/>
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner"/>
    <plugin name="Canvas2ImagePlugin" value="Canvas2ImagePlugin"/>
</plugins>
<access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: sure . where should i add the Canvas2ImagePlugin.h , Canvas2ImagePlugin.m   and  Canvas2ImagePlugin.js ?

Comment: .m and .h in /your-project/your-project/Plugins/, .js in /your-project/www/, alongside index.html. Make sure to add the .h and .m files as resources in Xcode